# Can you dynamically generate an initializer list?

Tags: c++

I have a class `MyClass` with no default constructor, and I want to create a `std::array<MyClass, 8>`. I believe I can initialize my array like this:

```
std::array<MyClass, 8> my_array = {
    {arg00, arg01, /* ... */, arg0N},
    {arg10, arg11, /* ... */, arg1N},
    /* ... */
    {arg70, arg71, /* ... */, arg7N}
};
```

where `argij` is the j-nth argument (out of N) of the i-nth element's constructor (out of 8). Now, spelling out these arguments is a boring and error prone business, and it is much more clear and straightforward to automatically generate/assemble them, which can be done as something like this:

```
for(uint8_t a = 0; a < 2; ++a) {
    for(uint8_t b = 0; b < 2; ++b) {
        for(uint8_t c = 0; c < 2; ++c) {
            std::tie(arg0, arg1, /* ... */, argN) = generate_args(a, b, c);

            /* TODO: do something with arg0, arg1 ... argN */
        }
    }
}
```

So, the question: is there a way to create my `std::array<MyClass, 8> my_array;` from the dynamically generated constructor arguments?

EDIT:

Currently I have a default constructor on `MyClass`, so I can initialize `my_array[counter++] = MyClass(args...);` from inside the loops. But I don't like allowing `MyClass` to be created in an uninitialized state.

Comment: Can you show the constructor declaration?

Comment: initializer lists force a copy of their members, you may want to instead initialize `my_array[index]` directly

Comment: @AndyG That doesn't work if there is no default constructor.

Comment: @Holt it is very simple, it just copies the arguments to member variables.

Comment: Use a `std::vector`.  Solves most problems ;)

Comment: Something like this maybe: https://godbolt.org/z/JuDyFi

Comment: @Holt Looks very nice! Thanks. WIll you make an answer?

Comment: Yeah, I had the same want & wrote a `make_array()` helper to enable variadically constructing array elements from arbitrarily formulae based on the index of each, passed to a lambda that returns the element.

Comment: @lvella I cannot write an answer right now (on the mobile app), but feel free to adapt the code to your needs and post it as a self answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't work with initializer lists like that.  But you might be able to borrow a trick from `std::experimental::to_array()` and use a `std::index_sequence` template to convert a suitable vector:

```
template <std::size_t... I>
static constexpr std::array<MyClass, 8>
to_array(std::vector<MyClass>&& v, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return { {v[I]...} };
}


const std::array<MyClass, 8> my_array =
    []{
        std::vector<MyClass> v;
        for(uint8_t a = 0; a < 2; ++a) {
            for(uint8_t b = 0; b < 2; ++b) {
                for(uint8_t c = 0; c < 2; ++c) {
                    int arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3;
                    std::tie(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3) = generate_args(a, b, c);
                    v.emplace_back(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
                }
            }
        }
        return to_array(std::move(v), std::make_index_sequence<8>{});
    }();
```

If your `MyClass` isn't copyable or movable, perhaps directly construct into the array with a similar index sequence template (but generate `a`, `b` and `c` back from the index):

```
template <std::size_t... I>
constexpr std::array<MyClass, 8>
generate(std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    auto create =
        [](std::size_t i) {
            const auto& [arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3]
                = generate_args((i>>2)&1, (i>>1)&1, (i>>0)&1);
            return MyClass{arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3};
        };
    return { create(I)... };
}


const std::array<MyClass, 8> my_array = generate(std::make_index_sequence<8>{});
```

Comment: Sorry, but yikes! A variadic, constructing in-place (especially in C++17, with guaranteed copy elision) solution like Holt's would be far preferable. Anyhow, won't your `to_array()` need to `std::move( v[I] )`, otherwise it'll get copied?

Comment: I haven't seen Holt's yet - as I'm writing, this is the only answer.

Comment: Ok, maybe the initializer list is not "dynamically" generated, as in dynamically allocating it, but it is certainly automatic in `{ create((I>>2)&1, (I>>1)&1, (I>>0)&1)... }`.

Comment: @underscore_d, as you were writing, I was improving for non-copyable (and also non-movable) types.  Still can't see a way to avoid the variadic template, though.

Comment: I'd be tempted to fabricate `a, b, c` in the body of `create`, and just `return { create(I)... };`

Comment: Yes, that's probably easier to comprehend @Caleth; I've edited to do that.